# Unable to find the slot of arduino though Qt

Tags: c++, qt

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QString>
#include <string>
#include <QObject>


Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //ui->degree_lcdNumber->display("---");
   // ui->distance_lcdNumber->display("---");
    arduino_is_available = false;
    port_name = "";
    arduino =new QSerialPort;
    serialBuffer = "";

    foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortInfo, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
        if(serialPortInfo.hasVendorIdentifier() &&serialPortInfo.hasProductIdentifier()){
            if(serialPortInfo.vendorIdentifier() == arduino_uno_vendorid){
                if(serialPortInfo.productIdentifier()== arduino_uno_productid){
                    port_name = serialPortInfo.portName();
                    arduino_is_available = true;

                }
            }
        }

    }
    if(arduino_is_available){
        //open and configure the port
        arduino->setPortName(port_name);
        arduino->open(QSerialPort::ReadOnly);
        arduino->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
        arduino->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
        arduino->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
        arduino->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
        arduino->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    QObject::connect(arduino,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(&serialReceived()));

    }else{
        //give error message
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"Port Error","Couldn't find the Arduino!");
    }
}


Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    if(arduino->isOpen()){
        arduino->close();
    }
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::serialReceived(){

    qDebug()<<"works" ;
    QStringList bufferSplit = serialBuffer.split(".");

        serialData = arduino->readAll();
        serialBuffer += QString::fromStdString(serialData.toStdString());

     serialBuffer  = ",";
                      qDebug()<<bufferSplit;
}
void Dialog::updateLCD(const QString sensor_reading){
//    ui->degree_lcdNumber->display(sensor_reading);
}
```

---

(.h)

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QSerialPort>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    QSerialPort *arduino;
    static const quint16 arduino_uno_vendorid =9025;
    static const quint16 arduino_uno_productid =67;
    void updateLCD(const QString);
    void serialReceived();
    QString port_name;
    //void readSerial();
    QByteArray serialData;
    QString serialBuffer;
    bool arduino_is_available;

};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

I just started the Qt. I want to connect Qt with arduino serially. I am reading the data but I am not able to connect with arduino slot.
I am getting a message after compilation. The message is QObject::connect: No such slot Dialog::&serialReceived() in ..\serial_sensor\dialog.cpp:45
QObject::connect: (receiver name: 'Dialog').

Can I know why?

Comment: your serialReceived() function must be declared as a SLOT if you wish to use it as such. Add a "public slots:" section in your dialog's declaration and move your serialReceived() declaration there.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Qt Signals and Slot documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html), the Qt signals and slots have to be declared under `signals:` and `public slots:` respectively.

**Why do we do that ?**

*Since slots are normal member functions, they follow the normal C++ rules when called directly. However, as slots, they can be invoked by any component, regardless of its access level, via a signal-slot connection. This means that a signal emitted from an instance of an arbitrary class can cause a private slot to be invoked in an instance of an unrelated class.**( as per Qt Documentation)***

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~Dialog();

public slots :
    void serialReceived();

signals :
    // Declare Signals here.

private:
   // other private declarations.

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your connection is failing is that *your connect syntax is wrong*. Either you have mixed Qt's functor and string based connections or accidentally added & in front of serialReceived. Below you can find two ways to do your connection. The first one is preferred. You can read more from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html). Because Dialog is QObject based class you can just call connect.

Functor based connection:

```
connect(arduino, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &Dialog::serialReceived);
```

String based connection:

```
connect(arduino, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(serialReceived()));
```

If you are using Qt4 you have to use `slots` in your declaration. In Qt5 `slots` is not strictly required for connections but it should still be used. If you don't use it you can't use introspection. You can't e.g. call `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`. So, in short add slots to your header file as others have already suggested.

```
public slots:
    void serialReceived();
```